# automatic build and deploy fails with build failure on jazzhub

Tags: eclipse, jazz, ibm-cloud, ibm-jazz

I am trying to use the feature of jazzhub (IBM DevOps offerings) of automatically build and deploy on Bluemix. I have used Eclipse plugin for Jazzhub to check in my code to my project. However automatic build always fails with the below type of error.

using .gitcredentials to set credentials
Checking out Revision a0b1e7c78b02e82ad210bc369cdd633212cb544f (origin/master)
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[47f4a135-016e-4a75-bb42-f9a9fda6df05] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson3124921405781328608.sh
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Connecting to https://P90JEN01.sl.jazz.net:9444*

I am able to build and deploy the same code base from Eclipse directly to bluemix.  My understanding is that DevOps service create build.xml file automatically if It does not find one. The document says it

"A project relative path where the build scripts are found and executed. The project root will be used if empty. A default build script (e.g., Ant build.xml file or Grunt Gruntfile.js file) will be generated and delivered to your source control system if one is not found. You may need to edit the generated build script to fit your needs".

Can anyone help me here? how to get pass this error and make a build successfully deployed ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we may need to create build.xml if you are using ant script:

http://thoughtsoncloud.com/2014/10/create-deploy-stand-alone-java-application-ibm-bluemix/

"The next step is to create the script to build the code. In this example, I created an .ant script. You can write in the language of your choice from the options supported in Bluemix. Create a file named build.xml and write the .ant build script."